# View Errors happened in Database (Remote) – SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

Our application is using SQL Server 2005 as the database. We are using a history database to which the actual database is putting values using trigger.

I checked the DB server. It was set as 600 sec for the Remote Query Timeout. I changed as zero and restarted the server.

Still, we are getting errors during the operations if we enable the above mentioned triggers, after 10 minutes. This is working fine if we don’t use triggers.

I would like to use profiler to see all the errors happened in the two databases. How do I configure the profiler to see only errors from the above mentioned two databases? Otherwise, is there any query or DMV to see all the errors happened in databases?

**Note: I want to see errors only in profiler; not all other details**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the profiler check the box 'show all columns', then you can choose 'DatabaseName' in the columns and then set a filter on it to show only your db names.

There is a category in the events for errors and warnings. 

Here's a good [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175481.aspx) reference for the error events.

Comment: When you create a trace it selects Security Audit and others as defaults. Make sure you uncheck those and only have Errors and Warnings selected.

Answer (score 1):

you can filter the database name in profiler, see below
You need to check "show all columns" in order to see it

To only see errors, click on `show all events`, then pick `errors and warnings` and select the ones you want, unselect all the other stuff you don't want

[image]